# how to put html in a .module php file

Tags: 7, blocks

I have a input box created with html need to put in the specific block. I saw posts writing there to add the html by function but i cant do it since it is php file
Is it right way to do this? what is the exactly way to do this?
    function firstmodule_block_view($delta = ''){

```
$block = array();

switch ($delta) {   
    case 'signup':
    $block['subject'] = t('Newsletter signup');
    $block['content'] = myblock();
    break;
}       
    return $block;
}

function myblock(){
//html code goes here????
}
```

Comment: Forget Drupal for a second - how would you 'put html' in any other PHP file? Knowing what you're expecting to happen will make it easier to point you in the right direction for a proper Drupal solution to this, as at the moment it looks like you're just asking a very basic PHP question

Comment: @Clive i wanna put a html input box in a block, how to do that?

Comment: If you literally just want some markup, just `return '<some>markup</some>';` from your function. But you probably want to look at the [Form generation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/group/form_api/7) topic

Answer (score 1):

So first you want to define a block that contains a form. You define the contents of a block in `$block['content']`.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 */
function MYMODULE_block_info() {
  $blocks['your_block_name'] = array(
    'info' => t('Name of your block'), 
    'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
  );
  return $blocks;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 */
function MYMODULE_block_view($delta='')
{
  switch($delta) {
    case 'your_block_name':
      $block['subject'] = null;
      $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('MYMODULE_form');
      break;
  }
  return $block;
}
```

An after that you need to define your form. In Drupal you use the [Form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) to build forms. In the example above we fetch the form called MYMODULE_form. And the form is defined by implementing [hook_form()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_form/7).

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form().
 */
function MYMODULE_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['MYINPUTBOX'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('My label')
  );
  return $form;
}
```